# Split Dataframe into multiple dataframes after a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a dataframe in the below format into multiple dataframes based on specific value.

```
Column0              Column1     Column2  Column3
Question             Answer      Reason   30
It is received?      XXX         YYY      27
Deducted             FDF         RES      64
Transferred?         WWW         RRR      64
Transport Services   Passgener   Carrier  30
Distance             KKK         WDF      27
Return               PPP         LMN      64
```

In the above dataframe,I want to split the rows starting from Event2 or Code = 30 (specific color code or Header code) into separate dataframe and rest (which are above) into other dataframe (There may be more than two events also.).

I have tried few codes but most of them are for filtering purpose.

Expected output is:
Dataframe1:

```
Question             Answer      Reason   30
It is received?      XXX         YYY      27
Deducted             FDF         RES      64
Transferred?         WWW         RRR      64
```

Dataframe2:

```
Transport Services   Passgener   Carrier  30
Distance             KKK         WDF      27
Return               PPP         LMN      64
```

Please help as I am new to python.

Comment: Is your `Question` column an `index` or usual column?

Comment: It is not an index but an usual column only...values  may repeat at times  @AntonProtopopov

Comment: Question + Answer is unique

Comment: You can use pandas for this, check this tutorial:

http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/working-with-pandas-dataframes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `groupby` on a temporary helper `column` based on `Code` to separate out different `DataFrames` and add these to a `dictionary`. I'm assuming you meant the data to actually look like this to match the original schema:

```
             Question     Answer   Reason  Code
0     It is received?        XXX      YYY    30
1            Deducted        FDF      RES    64
2        Transferred?        WWW      RRR    64
3  Transport Services  Passgener  Carrier    30
4            Distance        KKK      WDF    27
5              Return        PPP      LMN    64
```

If so, you can do:

```
df['tmp'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Question if x.Code == 30 else np.nan, axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

to get:

```
             Question     Answer   Reason  Code                 tmp
0     It is received?        XXX      YYY    30     It is received?
1            Deducted        FDF      RES    64     It is received?
2        Transferred?        WWW      RRR    64     It is received?
3  Transport Services  Passgener  Carrier    30  Transport Services
4            Distance        KKK      WDF    27  Transport Services
5              Return        PPP      LMN    64  Transport Services
```

From here, you can `enumerate` the `groups` in the `tmp` columns and add the result to a `dictionary` with `integer` `keys`:

```
questions = {}
for e, (event, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('tmp')):
    questions[e] = data.drop('tmp', axis=1)

questions[0]

          Question Answer Reason  Code
0  It is received?    XXX    YYY    30
1         Deducted    FDF    RES    64
2     Transferred?    WWW    RRR    64

questions[1]

             Question     Answer   Reason  Code
3  Transport Services  Passgener  Carrier    30
4            Distance        KKK      WDF    27
5              Return        PPP      LMN    64
```

Comment: HI Stefan, I have given example as event1 and 2 here..but in actual..there are with different names like importance ,event,service etc.

Comment: But the other `Question` values are single letter? Or how do they differ systematically? Updated to base decision on single letter values.

Comment: other values are small sentences with explanations (they are not single letters).I have just given the sample format of the file.

Comment: So how do you distinguish the first row for every new data frame? Code 30? Your Sampler suggests that the first question row of every new frame is a word and all others are single letters. You are saying this is actually not the case?

Comment: See updated answer and let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Stefan...Thanks..this looks close to my requirement....let me give it a try and post it as an answer...

Comment: Hi Stefan ..that worked...thanks.Now,I am just curious to know whether is it possible to split based on first column in my dataframe rather than the code 30.For example,lets say that in Column0 there are many values and out of that one is that 'service covered'.Can I split based on that value alone?

Comment: Just to add to above...can we split the df if the column value contains or starts with particular key word like services irrespective of its case...condition is either code 30 or string contains...

Comment: Just modify the `apply` like so: df.apply(lambda x: x.Question if x.Code == 30 or x.Question=='services' else np.nan, axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')

Comment: @Stefan..I have thought of the same,but the issue here is that it might start with the word services or it might be there somewhere in a sentence in that column (assuming it occurs at that place only)...I have tried with str.contains("services",case=False) but couldnt get it working ...Also in my case at times..the headers are represented by just numbers ranging from 0 to n without any names